# Meanings of the word Islam

Tags: terminology, definitions

What is the base of the  Word Islam, it is Is and Lam combined, meaning Peace, it is P-e-ace, and what does it represents, can any one translate the word in its essence please.

Answer (score 0):

Meaning of ISLAM is PEASE

The triliteral root sīn lām mīm (س ل م) occurs 140 times in the Quran, in 16 derived forms

> In Quran, eight times used as the form IV verbal noun is'lām (إِسْلَٰم)

Muslim is also derived from the same root.

[See the Quranic Dictionary and usage of this word with meanding](http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=slm#(3:19:5))

Comment: Human do not speak words but make sounds like every other creation of Allah (St) Combination of Alf and Seen is one part,  and lam   being a word and a letter, meanings limit, Haad, such as Lam yakunilallah zenah, meaning the confined with in the will of Allah (St). Lam is not just  a letter only, but a word , a sound with in itself, a commandment. May be new for you but, a word, (commandment) with in itself. Unfortunately this fact has been deleted on purpose to fool humanity and  Muslims in particular  to control  understanding of the language by the crooks of dark ages.

Comment: Seems you have better knowledge of Arabic than me. See the verse 55: 3 & 4: He created human, taught him speech/eloquence, If you compare human speaking with animals then what about these two verses?

Comment: Have no doubt about it,  HE taught the language to human being s but, did they comprehend it? every word of Holy Quran is based on the limit of the Truth, and word spoken without truth are not the words, commandments but, demagoguery, foundation of un Islamic  out of perfection behavior of the Kafirs, the criminals.  Please pay attention, letters are not just the letters, but also words. Such as letter An, a letter and a word, meaning, according to, as in Araby, An, Ra, b, and Ya, meaning according to the Rab, as commanded by  The lord. If one is not according to the Rab, he is not an Araby.